# how to create a properties file for birt reports?

Tags: properties, birt

I have multiple BIRT reports that obtains the data from the same jdbc data source.
Is it possible to obtain the conection parameters (Driver URL, User Name, and Password) from an external property file or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could store your data sources in a library - see [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_SharedWorking.19.4.html) and [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_SharedWorking.19.1.html).