# how to write properties file for birt reports?

Tags: properties, birt

I have multiple BIRT reports that obtains the data from the same jdbc data source.

Is it possible to obtain the conection parameters (Driver URL, User Name, and Password) from an external property file or similar?

Please give one example for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a properties file for birt reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753386/how-to-create-a-properties-file-for-birt-reports)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create common connection in the library and use it in reports.

Step by step:

1. Create library: *File -> New -> Library*
2. In the *Outline* view create new *Data Source* the same way as you create report data source
3. For all reports:

   1. Open report
   2. In the *Resources* view find your newly created Data Source
   3. Right-click Data Source and choose *add to report*
   4. Switch Data Sets to Data Source from library

Due to [#343527](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=343527) you have to be carefull when editing *reports* referencing library conections. Correctly referenced connection (Data Source) has mini-icon that looks like a small blue chain. If connection data is altered locally, it has also yellow mini-icon looking like (hmm..) a small pencil. When you see it, open report XML Source, find `<oda-data-source>` tag and delete all its children.